# Issue with implementing recursive function for finding paths

Tags: c++, function, recursion

I'm trying to print out all possible paths in a subway system which has stations from A to L. In other words the objective is to find how many possible routes a person could take to get through a subway system without going over a track more than once.  I know there are 640 possible paths since I wrote this program using an adjacency matrix in C earlier. Now I'm trying to write the same program except using classes in C++ without the use of an adjacency matrix.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to properly implement my recursive function, SearchRoute, as I need to print the path, flag the path, and then unflag the path again to allow for backtracking. When I print out the final result I only get a track from A to B and that obviously means something is clearly wrong.

This is what I believe the problem is: I know that in my SubwaySystem::SearchRoute function I use an if and else statement which clearly does NOT allow my recursive function to be called but I tried putting another if statement instead of the else but I'm not quite sure what the condition would be.

```
void SubwaySystem::SearchRoute(int Current_Station_ID)
{
    while(Current_Station_ID < 33)
    {
        cout << "In while loop\n";
        // \\ Checking progress
        if(Current_Station_ID == 0)  //Find a successful route to Station L
        {
            count_routes++; //Add 1 into the variable “count_routes”
            cout << "In if statement\n";
            // \\Checking progress
            cout << count_routes << " " << my_track[Current_Station_ID] << endl; //Print out this route
            return;
        }
        else //Get into recursive Function Body
        {
            for(int i = my_station[Current_Station_ID].track_starting_ID; i < my_station[Current_Station_ID].track_starting_ID + my_station[Current_Station_ID].track_size; i++)
            {
                if(my_track[Current_Station_ID].visited == 0)  //if this track is not visited before
                {
                    cout << "In recursive part of function\n";
                    // \\ Checking progress
                    my_track[Current_Station_ID].visited = 1; //mark this track as visited
                    my_track[Current_Station_ID].node_2 = 1; //mark its corresponding track as visited
                    cout << my_track[Current_Station_ID] << endl; //save this track
                    SearchRoute(Current_Station_ID + 1); //Recursive
                    i--; //Backtrack this track
                    my_track[Current_Station_ID].visited = 0;//mark this track as unvisited
                    my_track[Current_Station_ID].node_2 = 0;//mark its corresponding track as unvisited
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also I tried putting in print statements along the way to track progress throughout the program. My recursive function never gets called for the reasons I specified above (at least that's why I think its not working). And for some reason that I can't figure out why my default and overload track constructors are called several times.

I would appreciate if you could help me figure out the problem areas in my code/ show me the correct way. I'm tired of thinking about this. Thanks in advance.

Here is the rest of the program in a single TU :

```
//Function Declarations
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef SUBWAY_H
#define SUBWAY_H

class Track
{
public:
    //Default Constructor
    Track();

    //Overload Constructor
    Track(char, char);

    //Destructor
    ~Track();

    //Member variables
    char node_1;
    char node_2;
    bool visited;
};

class Station
{
public:
    //Default Constructor
    Station();

    //Destructor
    ~Station();

    //Overload Constructor
    Station(char, int, int);

    //Member variables
    char station_name;
    int track_starting_ID;
    int track_size;
};

class SubwaySystem
{
public:
    //Default Constructor
    SubwaySystem();

    //Destructor
    ~SubwaySystem();

    //Recursive function
    void SearchRoute(int);

    //Other member functions
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Track& my_track);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Station& my_station);


    //Member variables
    Track my_track[34];
    Station my_station[12];

    int count_routes;
    int Current_Station_ID;

    //String to save found route
};

#endif

// **cpp**

//Function Definitions
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//#include "subway.h"

using namespace std;

Track::Track()
{
    visited = 0;
    //cout << "Default Track has been called\n";
    //\\ Checking progress
}


Track::~Track()
{
}


Track::Track(char pass_track1, char pass_track2)
{
    node_1 = pass_track1;
    node_2 = pass_track2;
    visited = false;
    //cout << "Overload Track constructor has been called\n";
    // \\ Checking progress
}


Station::Station()
{
}


Station::~Station()
{
}


Station::Station(char pass_station_name, int pass_start, int pass_size)
{
    station_name = pass_station_name;
    track_starting_ID = pass_start;
    track_size = pass_size;
    //cout << "Overload station has been called\n";
    // \\ Checking progress
}


SubwaySystem::SubwaySystem()
{
    //Initialize tracks
    //node_1, node_2
    my_track[0] = Track('a', 'b');
    my_track[1] = Track('b', 'a');
    my_track[2] = Track('b', 'c');
    my_track[3] = Track('b', 'd');
    my_track[4] = Track('b', 'e');
    my_track[5] = Track('b', 'f');
    my_track[6] = Track('c', 'b');
    my_track[7] = Track('c', 'e');
    my_track[8] = Track('d', 'b');
    my_track[9] = Track('d', 'e');
    my_track[10] = Track('e', 'b');
    my_track[11] = Track('e', 'c');
    my_track[12] = Track('e', 'd');
    my_track[13] = Track('e', 'g');
    my_track[14] = Track('e', 'h');
    my_track[15] = Track('f', 'b');
    my_track[16] = Track('f', 'h');
    my_track[17] = Track('g', 'e');
    my_track[18] = Track('g', 'k');
    my_track[19] = Track('h', 'e');
    my_track[20] = Track('h', 'f');
    my_track[21] = Track('h', 'i');
    my_track[22] = Track('h', 'j');
    my_track[23] = Track('h', 'k');
    my_track[24] = Track('i', 'h');
    my_track[25] = Track('i', 'k');
    my_track[26] = Track('j', 'h');
    my_track[27] = Track('j', 'k');
    my_track[28] = Track('k', 'g');
    my_track[29] = Track('k', 'h');
    my_track[30] = Track('k', 'i');
    my_track[31] = Track('k', 'j');
    my_track[32] = Track('k', 'l');
    my_track[33] = Track('l', 'k');
    //Initialize stations
    //station_name, track_starting_ID, track_size
    my_station[0] = Station('a', 0, 1);
    my_station[1] = Station('b', 1, 5);
    my_station[2] = Station('c', 6, 2);
    my_station[3] = Station('d', 8, 2);
    my_station[4] = Station('e', 10, 5);
    my_station[5] = Station('f', 15, 2);
    my_station[6] = Station('g', 17, 2);
    my_station[7] = Station('h', 19, 5);
    my_station[8] = Station('i', 24, 2);
    my_station[9] = Station('j', 26, 2);
    my_station[10] = Station('k', 28, 5);
    my_station[11] = Station('l', 33, 1);
    //Initiaize other members
    count_routes = 0;
    Current_Station_ID = 0;
    //cout << "SubwaySystem constructor called\n";
    // \\ Checking progress
}


SubwaySystem::~SubwaySystem()
{
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Track& my_track)
{
    os << my_track.node_1 << '.' << my_track.node_2;
    return os;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Station& my_station)
{
    os << my_station.station_name << '.' << my_station.track_starting_ID << '.' << my_station.track_size;
    return os;
}


//This is where the above recursive function SearchRoute goes. I posted it separately so it's easier to read.



// **main**

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

//#include "subway.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    SubwaySystem Test;
    Test.SearchRoute(0);
}
```

I'm sorry if the "Checking progress" print statements make it harder to read the code.

Comment: This is suppose to be a comment, but I can't post one yet since I don't the requirement yet. But anyways, I can see there's a few bugs in your recursive function. Currently there is a bug in your for loop, my_station only goes up to 11, but Current_Station_ID can pass that limit up to goes up to 33. If anyone could provide a way of fixing the bug if the OP can't. It may help since I can't quite think of a solution of the top of my head. EDIT: I'm not sure if the OP solved this or not. I'm wondering if anyone could still post a snippet of code which would fix the recursive function. I'm still i

Comment: **Where's all the question??** -1 for vandalizing your own question...

Comment: I'm sorry I'm at a friend's house and didn't realize he completely destroyed my question while he messing with my computer.. Thank you @Ken White for fixing it.

Comment: Please do not remove the content of a question. Please do not accept non answers. If you now know the answer, write your own answer.

Comment: @user98289 What is `track_starting_ID` supposed to mean?

Comment: This code has *numerous* errors, and we can't give you a "snippet" that will fix it. Do you want to learn how to write code? Here is the way to write code: start with the smallest, simplest code you can write that works, add complexity a little at a time, test at every step, and **never add to code that doesn't work.**

Comment: user98289 has a history of defacing questions.  See the discussion at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11315/18398

Answer (score 1):

You never enter recursion:

```
// this method is called with value 0
void SubwaySystem::SearchRoute(int Current_Station_ID)
{
    while(Current_Station_ID < 33)
    {
        cout << "In while loop\n";
        // \\ Checking progress
        if(Current_Station_ID == 0)  //Find a successful route to Station L
        {
            count_routes++; //Add 1 into the variable “count_routes”
            cout << "In if statement\n";
            // \\Checking progress
            cout << count_routes << " " << my_track[Current_Station_ID] << endl; //Print out this route
            return; // ERROR: here you return from the very 1st method call, breaking the search
        }
```

Comment: I see. I knew there was something wrong since the recursion part never takes off. The problem is that I don't know how to edit it for the recursion to work. I tried something like if(Current_Station_ID == 33) but I don't think that's quite the solution. I also tried to edit the loop conditions but I keep running into bugs like infinite loops or the program fails to compile. If you could maybe give me a possible condition that could work, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Basically without writing your code for you I suggest this:

Your recursive function should not have the while statement at all (the whole point of a recursive function is that it's a sort of a while statement in itself).

The first thing in your recursive function should be a check to see if you're station id is immediately adjacent to 'L' station or if the only path to take has already been taken. If it is adjacent you can return that there is a track from that station to L.

If there isn't, you call the recursive function for all the adjacent stations that have a path to them which you haven't travelled yet and use their results as part of the calculation for the station you are in at that moment.

To clarify with an example based on your data:

1. You first call the function with 'a' as a parameter.
2. The function's first checks if 'a' has a path to 'l' (it doesn't so the function does not return).
3. The function then calls itself **recursively** with all the stations that have a path from our current station 'a'. (only 'b')
4. From 'b' there is still no immediate track to 'l' so the function continues to call itself this time with 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'.
5. From the new call to the function with 'a', the first check discovers that the only available route, to 'b', has been taken already so it should return a negative response and not print anything.
6. When a call to the function with a station discovers that it has an immediate path to 'l', it should print (or store) that path segment and return true.
7. The recursive function collects all the results from its own recursive calls and adds the paths to those station's results.
8. Exact implementation depends on the output you need from the program. If you need to print out all the paths, you could hold a list of valid paths, adding a path whenever a new branching (more than one connected station) occurs and removing paths when you receive a negative return value from the recursive function. When the final call returns, you can print out the paths you've collected.

Does that clarify things?